# Output Available Objects and Properties in Liquid Templates

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

Is there a way to output (for debugging/informational purposes) the available objects and object properties in a [liquid template](http://liquidmarkup.org/)?

That is, say I'm using the jekyll site generation tool, and I'm in my `index.html` template (which is, to my understanding, a liquid template).   It might look something like this

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  <li><span>{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</span> &raquo; <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Are there any template tags I could use that would tell me/output a variable named `post` was available in this template (as well as the other templates).  Also, are there any template tags I could use that would tell me the `post` object has the keys `date`, `title`, `url`, `excerpt`, `permalink`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this from a Liquid template that I'm aware of. I used the following bit of Ruby code to do it in a test for Jekyll though (`setup_post` is a helper method in Jekyll's test suite)

```
post = setup_post("2008-11-21-complex.textile")
classes = []
Liquid::Template.parse(post.content).root.nodelist.each do |token|
  classes << token.name if token.is_a?(Liquid::Variable)
end
```

It should be possible to write a Jekyll plugin that could output this stuff on your page based on the above code.